Setting up SSH server in a Spark Master Docker Image
I have an Apache Spark Cluster running on docker, I want to set up an ssh server with the spark master in order to be able to ssh (to spark) from another service.
This is the docker-compose.yaml file of my spark cluster:
# this is a docker compose file for setting up an Apache Spark cluster
# 1 master and 2 worker nodes

services:
  spark-master:
    build: ./spark-master-ssh-server/
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9095:8080" 
      - "7777:7077"
      - "22222:22"  # exposing ssh ports
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-1:
    build: .
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      #SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      #SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network

  spark-worker-2:
    build: .
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      #SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      #SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 2g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - ./spark_jobs:/opt/spark_jobs
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    networks:
      - spark-network


networks:
  spark-network:
    driver: bridge


**
The content of the ./spark-master-ssh-server/Dockerfile (for Spark Master) is the following:**
FROM bitnami/spark:latest

# Installing SSH server
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y openssh-server

# Creating an SSH user
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/sshuser -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 sshuser

# Setting the SSH user's password
RUN echo 'sshuser:password' | chpasswd

## Generating SSH host keys
RUN ssh-keygen -A 

# Exposing the SSH port
EXPOSE 22

# Starting SSH server on container startup
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

# Switching to sshuser
USER sshuser

when I run the containers and execute the shell of the spark master container:

ssh is being installed correctly but it is not running:

sshuser@6142e5958a8e:/opt/bitnami/spark$ service ssh status
sshd is not running ... failed!



A Docker container only runs a single process, and not a full init system, and so commands like service don't usually show the one thing that's running.  Since it runs one process, it runs Spark or the sshd, and the Compose command: override is causing it to run only Spark.

ssh in Docker is pretty hard to configure securely (is your password really password; does it bother you that the password is written in plain text and is visible in docker history of the image?).  Do you have a specific use case that requires it?  Can you interact with the Spark system in some other way?  If this is just for human operator use, can they docker exec a debugging shell?

@DavidMaze actually the password is for demonstration purposes, I am still trying things out in a development environment.
And I wanted to configure ssh on a spark master so that an external service, a job scheduler in my case (Apache Airflow) can submit remotely a spark job to the spark master.
